# Create many shape file from a large shape file.

Tags: r

I have a shape file with two different region with 12 sub region each.I want separate shape file of these 24 sub region from that shape file.I have also tried by using package maptools and rgeos but could not figure it.Any logarithm would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

sharif

Comment: Please provide us with the R code of what you have already tried, preferably reproducible unto the point you are stuck. `could not figure it out` is quite vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your data in a loop based on the unique value in the column of interest and write out the subset data. I am using rgdal in leu of maptools but you could easily change the code to use maptools functions for reading/writing shapefiles.

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)

# READ SHAPEFILE
dat <- readOGR("C:/DATA", "dat")

# CREATE VECTOR OF UNIQUE SUBREGION VALUES
y <- unique(dat@data$SUBREGIONS)

# CREATE SHAPEFILE FOR EACH SUBREGION AND WRITE OUT 
  for (i in 1:length(y) ) {
    temp <- dat[dat$SUBREGIONS == y[i], ]   
  writeOGR(temp, dsn=getwd(), y[i], driver="ESRI Shapefile", 
           overwrite_layer=TRUE)
   }
```